# Infomatica Reading From Metadata

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a metadata Name as CONTACTS(SOURCE.CSV|TAGET.CSV). Now I read this file using reader and populate the value in table that I created as CONTACT_TABLE(PK NUMBER, Source_name varchar2(500),target_name varchar2(500)) after that I want to read these source.csv and target.csv file stored in my table CONTACT_TABLE AND populate the value in other table called SOURCE_COLUMN_TARGET_COLUMN_TABLE(PK,FK as pk of contact_table,source_column,target_column) this table should contain all the column of source and target and should have one to one relationship with that, for example, source.csv(fn)-----target.csv(firstName)

My objective is whenever we add some other attribute in source or target I should not change the entire mapping for eg if we add source.csv(email) and target.csv(email) it should directly map

Thanks! 
please help!
I have this task completed before Friday and I searched every source I found dynamic mapping thing and parameter thing but it was not very helpful I want to do this way itself

Comment: Not clear what you are asking actually

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are asking actually. The source analyser uses source files(.csv) on import itself and thereby contains the same format in source qualifier.

So, if any of the values gets added into your existing files (source.csv, target.csv) then it becomes a new file for your existing mapping. hence, you dont need to change the whole mapping just that you need to import it again.